# Expo notifications - no sound

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm building a React Native/Expo app that uses Push Notifications. For them to work I'm using package expo-notifications as shown below:

First, I'm setting notification handler

```
    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: false
      })
    })
```

Then I get push token:

```
const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
  let pushToken
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync()
    let finalStatus = existingStatus
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync()
      finalStatus = status
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert(I18n.t('errors.push.token'))
      return
    }
    pushToken = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data
    AsyncStorage.getItem('push_token').then((savedToken) => {
      if (pushToken !== savedToken) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('push_token', pushToken)
        Networking.registerDeviceForPushNotifications(pushToken, Platform.OS)
      }
    })
    console.log(pushToken)
  } else {
    alert(I18n.t('errors.push.physical'))
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: Colors.primary,
      sound: 'default'
    })
  }

  return pushToken
}
```

At the end I'm starting listeners:

```
    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
      setNotification(notification)
    })

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
      // navigation here
    })
```

**The problem:**

The notifications send to my app go through normally, but whatever I do I cannot get sound to work. I want my push messages to play a default system sound when they arrive, but there's nothing and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snipped that refers to `Notifications.setNotificationHandler` only fires when the app is foregrounded according to the docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#handling-incoming-notifications-when-the-app-is). You will have to send a test notification on a physical device with the app foregrounded to hear a sound.

It may also help to add a custom sound. This is handled in the app.json file and will require a rebuild but you can see an example and read more [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#example-appjson-with-config-plugin)